# VBA ACCESS Como actualizar los labels de un form sin usar Requery, Recal o Refresh

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un subForm que recibe datos de una tabla. Cada cierto tiempo modifico los valores de la tabla con una consulta de actualización lanzada por un Timer cada minuto. Quisiera refrescar los valores del form provenientes de la tabla sin usar Requery, Recal o Refresh para evitar el parpadeo que realiza el form al repintar todo. Hay alguna forma de actualizar los valores sin repintar.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la parte de la respuesta, os dejo el enlace por si le puede ayudar a alguien. Funcionaría para formularios principales para subformularios continuos comos es mi caso no funciona.

https://www.todoexpertos.com/preguntas/ac658rr7cpwcoiox/vba-access-como-actualizar-los-labels-de-un-form-sin-usar-requery-recal-o-refresh

https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Access/1725631-ACCESS-VBA-evitar-parpadeo-al-actualizar-un-form-con-el-Time.html#i1725675

Saludos y gracias por vuestra ayuda